# How can I "crop" an image in the shape of any alphanumeric character?

Tags: graphics

How can I punch cut an alphanumeric character, say, "A" out of an image, so that I have only the interior of a large bold "A" showing the contents of the image?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Why don't you prepare the image in the graphics programme of your choice and then just include it with `\includegraphics`? There really isn't any reason to spend time computing this during compilation, surely?

Comment: Even if the image is a tikz picture you could still do as @cfr suggests by compiling just the picture as standalone. But there are cases in which you might want to do it programmatically (some sort of fancy chapter number graphic, or a date) so I for one is be interested to see a a TeX solution. More common words would be *clip* or *mask*

Comment: I have to say though, that the acepted answer there doesn't work for me at the moment

Comment: The accepted answer fails for me because evince for windows can't display it, not because there's anything wrong with the answer. However I recommend an alternative using `transparency group=knockout]` (see section 23.5 of the Ti*k*Z manual)